# How to conditionally run script based on option from select menu?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a list of states in an option menu.  I'd like to run a bit of jquery only when either CA or NV are selected.  Here is what I have:

```
$('#state').change(function(){  var text=$('#state :selected').val();  
$('.st').val(text);      
});
```

Which I tried (unsuccessfully) to adapt to another bit of jquery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#state").change(function() {
          if ($("#state option[value='CA']").attr('selected')) {



$('#state').change(function(){  var text=$('#state :selected').val();  
$('.st').val(text);      
});



          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Any idea what needs to be changed for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if ($("#state").val() == "CA")
```

[`jQuery val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will return the selected value from a `select` element.

Here's a working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/HnK89/)

**EDIT:** And here's one that clears the value too: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/rFVr4/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#state").change(function() {
        var state = $(this).val();
        $(".st").val((state  == "CA") ? state : "");
    })
});
```

Comment: There is one issue now in that if a user selects CA and then goes back and selects another state, the value remains CA.  What would I need to add in order to make anything else reset the value?

Comment: @Paul: the value of what remains CA? The textbox?

Comment: @Paul: See the edit in my answer, I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Aww, Town, so close - What I am actually looking to do is not so much clear the value as to reset the value to what it was initially.  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
      if ($("#state option[value='CA']:checked").length > 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#state").change(function() {
      if ($("#state").val()=='CA') {
          //do something
         }    
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this, slight edit of Town's code (to account for t states and have a non blank default value:

`<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() { $("#state").change(function() { var state = $(this).val(); $(".st").val((state == "CA" || state == "NV") ? state : "auto"); }) }); </script>`